# How can I measure whether my live chat is optimal or not?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a website where there will be many 1v1 live chats.

How can I measure whether I have made optimal system or not? Is it possible to do that? Can I *"fake"* many users somehow and then get the answer if my system will take lots of resources or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Optimal" is a pretty vague word. It would probably be better to first determine what aspects you want to look at (database read/writes, latency issues, robustness to interference) and test those specifically.

Comment: @eykanal: I want to test as many aspects as possible to make a website fast and which eats little resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're referring to something called [**load testing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing).

You could check out many of the commercial offerings (in link) or you could simply roll your own using cURL or sockets, depending on how you implemented the chat system (combining this with timers, verbose logging and system commands that check resource usage, you can get a good idea as to how your system performs under stress).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load test your site, here's a link:

http://www.loadtestingtools.org/?opensource

If you want to know about optimizing php, I'd recommend

http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test specific actions a user would complete in a browser, we've had good experiences working with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

You may just be able to simulate this in your own code much more easily.